# Windows - No module named setuptools inspite installing it

Tags: python, module, package, anaconda, setuptools

I'm using conda version 4.12.0. OS is Windows 10.

I have installed setuptools successfully.

```
python -c "import setuptools"
```

The above command gives no error, indicating setuptools is indeed present.

But when I run a install.sh file, which calls a setup.py file which uses setuptools, it gives an error.

I ran the following command

```
(consistent_depth) C:\Users\a0502200\Desktop\consistent_depth>"./scripts/install.sh"
```

Below is the install.sh file :-

```
# conda create -n consistent_depth python=3.6
# conda activate consistent_depth
# Note to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH if conda activate fails to do so.
pip install -r requirements.txt -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
pushd third_party/flownet2
chmod +x install.sh
./install.sh
popd
```

Following is the error that's coming :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\a0502200\Desktop\consistent_depth\third_party flownet2\networks\correlation_package\setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\a0502200\Desktop\consistent_depth\third_party flownet2\networks\resample2d_package\setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

Below is the setup.py file (correlation_package):-

```
import os
# import torch

from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from torch.utils.cpp_extension import BuildExtension, CUDAExtension

cxx_args = ['-std=c++11']

nvcc_args = [
    '-gencode', 'arch=compute_50,code=sm_50',
    '-gencode', 'arch=compute_52,code=sm_52',
    '-gencode', 'arch=compute_60,code=sm_60',
    '-gencode', 'arch=compute_61,code=sm_61',
    '-gencode', 'arch=compute_70,code=sm_70',
    '-gencode', 'arch=compute_70,code=compute_70'
]

setup(
    name='correlation_cuda',
    ext_modules=[
        CUDAExtension('correlation_cuda', [
            'correlation_cuda.cc',
            'correlation_cuda_kernel.cu'
        ], extra_compile_args={'cxx': cxx_args, 'nvcc': nvcc_args})
    ],
    cmdclass={
        'build_ext': BuildExtension
    })
```

Attaching a screenshot for the complete reference.
Why is this problem occurring? What's the solution?
[image: The region of error is highlighted by blue]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Text, please! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. [edit] your question, copy/paste from the terminal and properly [format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors, fonts, screen positions, etc).

Comment: Please [edit] and include the command you ran.

Comment: Hi, I added the screenshot because Iwanted to show the entire activity of the cmd.

Comment: I have now added the specific error lines as text also

Comment: You tested with `python -c "import setuptools"` but the script is run under `/usr/bin/env python3`. Most probably `python` and `python3` are 2 different Pythons. Check with `where python` vs `where python3`;  `python --version` vs `python3 --version`.

Comment: This line was commented (the # perhaps did not get copied). I've now added it.

Comment: So I don't think this is the problem

Comment: In this particular place (the beginning of the 1st line of a script) it's not a comment, it's a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). Though I must admit I don't know how shebangs are recognized by Python on Windows; I almost never used Windows.

Comment: I removed the entire line. Still it doesn't work....
Same error